# AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'write'

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, floating-point

I want to write variable time to txt. file, but I get error:

```
for x in range(0, 500):

    t1 = timeit.default_timer()
    x=x+1
    t.write(str(t1) + '\n')

    t = timeit.default_timer() - t1
    print("Pretecen cas: ", t)

    break
```

The output is:

```
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'write'
```

Comment: `t` is a float. `t` does not have a function for write. `t` shouldn't be a float. Read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

You would need to create a file object to write to a file. Looks like you are using a variable of type `float` to write to file. Here is a simple code snippet to write to file:

```
f = open('file.txt', 'w')
t1 = 0.850666426
f.write(str(t1)+'\n')
f.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
t1=0.850666426

with open('myfile.csv',"w") as f:
    f.write(str(t1) + '\n')
```